# Fatal error: Cannot use isset, use null expression

Tags: php, html

I keep receiving the error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you
>   can use "null !== expression" instead) in line 42

This is line 42:

```
if (isset($_GET['reply_id'] && $_GET['reply_user'])) {
```

Here's the "entire" part of that code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['reply_id'] && $_GET['reply_user'])) {
$reply_id = $_GET['reply_id'];
$reply_user = $_GET['reply_user'];
echo '<form action="#" method="post">
<center>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="300" name="comment_box" placeholder="Say something awesome..." Style="width:94%;font-family:helvetica;font-size:14px;">@' . $reply_user . '.</textarea></center>
<center><input type="submit" name="post2" class="post_text" value="Post"></center>
</form>';
}
?>
```

**How do I fix this?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you mean

```
 if ( isset($_GET['reply_id'], $_GET['reply_user']) ) {
      // code here
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Late reply, but usually this error is caused by a typo or syntax error.

```
(isset($_GET['reply_id'], $_GET['reply_user']))

(isset($_GET['reply_id']) && isset($_GET['reply_user']))
```

Both are fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing with this condition.

```
if (isset($_GET['reply_id']) && isset($_GET['reply_user'])) {
 // your code.
}
```

Comment: @PHPWebDev101 Try to copy it properly. I have tried it by assigning both the GET parameter to value 1.

Answer (score 0):

make sure isset is receiving simple expressions. Ex:

instead of

```
if(isset(old('name'))){
//...
}
```

do something like

```
$name = old('name');

if(isset($name)){
//...
}
```